# Postgresql regex extract all texts between parentheses

Tags: regex, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, I have a text value `foo (text1) bar (text2)`, I want to regex match and extract all the texts between parentheses

```
SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES('foo (text1) bar (text2)', '\((.*)\)', 'g')
```

I got this response:

```
regex_matches
-------------------
{text1) bar (text2}
```

I expect the output to be:

```
regex_matches
-------------------
text1
text2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this regex: `\(([^\(]*)\)`

Query:

```
SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES('foo (text1) bar (text2)', '\(([^\(]*)\)', 'g');
```

`regex_matches` return matches with curly brackets. If you want remove curly brackes ( `{` ).. then try with this below query:

```
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING( REGEXP_MATCHES('foo (text1) bar (text2)', '\(([^\(]*)\)', 'g'), '');
```

Comment: This answer is good, but it will return also empty value in case  you have this in your string foo (text1) bar (text2) (). To avoid that, try this `\(([^\(]+)\)`